# React renders only the first element when render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React with [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html). The problem is with the CommentList component - // tutorial10.js. For some reason only the first element from the commentNodes array is displayed and the others are not. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show use your entire code? or the data.length?

Comment: commentNodes array has 2 elements of type ReactElement. When I use commentNodes[1] the second element is rendered, but {commentNodes} shows only the first one.

Comment: Hmm, share us your code please

Comment: Yes share code and do a fiddle plz :)

Comment: This is my code - [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/R1YcTcy8)